# Gtest RecordProperty() for testsuite attribute

Tags: xml, googletest, test-suite

Using Google test framework for unit testing, is it possible to configure the output XML file attributes? I know it's possible for `'test case'` attribute. Is it possible to configure the top level attributes(`'testsuite'` or `'testsuites'`) of the XML file?

This is what I got from the documentation: *Calling `RecordProperty()` outside of the lifespan of a test is allowed. If it's called outside of a test but between a test case's `SetUpTestCase()` and `TearDownTestCase()` methods, it will be attributed to the XML element for the test case. If it's called outside of all test cases (e.g. in a test environment), it will be attributed to the top-level XML element.*

It says it's possible, but couldn't get how to make it work. Where exactly is the `RecordProperty` to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an elementary example.

**gtester.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

struct my_fixture : ::testing::Test
{
    void SetUp() {
        std::cout << "Calling " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

    }
    void TearDown() {
        std::cout << "Calling " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }    
};

TEST_F(my_fixture,foo)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(1,1);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    ::testing::Test::RecordProperty("GlobalProperty", "TopLevel");
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile and link:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o gtester gtester.cpp -pthread -lgtest
```

Run, with XML output:

```
$ ./gtester --gtest_output=xml:./gtester.xml
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from my_fixture
[ RUN      ] my_fixture.foo
Calling virtual void my_fixture::SetUp()
Calling virtual void my_fixture::TearDown()
[       OK ] my_fixture.foo (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from my_fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

And the XML test report is:

```
$ cat gtester.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="1" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" timestamp="2017-11-22T19:24:53" time="0" GlobalProperty="TopLevel" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="my_fixture" tests="1" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
    <testcase name="foo" status="run" time="0" classname="my_fixture" />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

in which `<testsuites>` has the property `GlobalProperty="TopLevel"`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/092d0885332316ca679ac77e0f8fe1f5c368fb4f/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L425) of gtest I found the following explanation for the function `RecordProperty()` which exactly answers your question:

> Calls to `RecordProperty()` made during lifespan of the test (from the moment its constructor starts to the moment its destructor finishes) will be output in XML as attributes of the `<testcase>` element.  Properties recorded from fixture's `SetUpTestCase()` or `TearDownTestCase()` are logged as attributes of the corresponding `<testsuite>` element.  Calls to `RecordProperty()` made in the global context (before or after invocation of `RUN_ALL_TESTS` and from `SetUp()`/`TearDown()` method of Environment objects registered with Google Test) will be output as attributes of the `<testsuites>` element.

Furthermore the following example clarifies the previous mentioned specification:

**gtest_example.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct exampleFixture : ::testing::Test {
  static void SetUpTestCase() { RecordProperty("TestsuiteProperty", "I am an attribute of TESTSUITE."); }
  void SetUp() { RecordProperty("TestCaseProperty1", "I am an attribute of TESTCASE, added from exampleFixture::SetUp()"); }
};

TEST_F(exampleFixture, testFeatureX) {
  RecordProperty("TestCaseProperty2", "I am an attribute of TESTCASE, added from testFeatureX()");
  ASSERT_TRUE(true);
}

TEST_F(exampleFixture, testFeatureY) {
  RecordProperty("TestCaseProperty3", "I am an attribute of TESTCASE, added from testFeatureY()");
  ASSERT_TRUE(true);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    ::testing::Test::RecordProperty("TestsuitesProperty", "I am an attribute of TESTSUITES");   

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Running the compiled executable with the command line argument `--gtest_output=xml:report.xml` will generate the file **report.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="2" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" timestamp="2018-02-18T17:11:33" time="0" 
   TestsuitesProperty="I am an attribute of TESTSUITES" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="exampleFixture" tests="2" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0"
      TestsuiteProperty="I am an attribute of TESTSUITE.">
    <testcase name="testFeatureX" status="run" time="0" classname="exampleFixture"
      TestCaseProperty1="I am an attribute of TESTCASE, added from exampleFixture::SetUp()" 
      TestCaseProperty2="I am an attribute of TESTCASE, added from testFeatureX()" />
    <testcase name="testFeatureY" status="run" time="0" classname="exampleFixture" 
      TestCaseProperty1="I am an attribute of TESTCASE, added from exampleFixture::SetUp()" 
      TestCaseProperty3="I am an attribute of TESTCASE, added from testFeatureY()" />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```